# gcc creates mime type application/x-sharedlib instead of application/x-application

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, mime-types

Given the following C++ code 'mini.cpp':

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the compiler command:

```
g++ -o hello mini.cpp
```

the result of

```
mimetype hello
```

is

```
hello: application/x-sharedlib
```

How do I get 'application/x-application' as a mime type?

I'm using gcc 6.2.0 on Kubuntu.

Comment: What is `mimetype`?

Comment: try `file -i hello`

Comment: mimetype is just a script. The background of my question is different: I cannot execute an application with the wrong mimetype from the file explorer or from the taskbar .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

gcc doesn't set the mime type. `mimetype` guesses the appropriate mime type based on the contents of the file. For ELF files (most compiled binaries and shared libraries), [the header](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) contains a field `e_type` which identifies its type. If it is `ET_DYN`, then `mimetype` will treat it as a shared library.

By default, gcc/ld will produce binaries which set `e_type` to `ET_EXEC`, which get detected as `application/x-executable`. When the command-line option `-pie` is used, a position-independent executable is created, which may, like shared libraries, be loaded at different addresses and still work. Because this works so much like a shared library, to avoid too many changes to the loader, such binaries get marked as `ET_DYN`, even though they can be executed directly.

Some Linux distributions, yours included, have set `-pie` as the default. It's still possible to override this with `-no-pie`, but the fact that the mime type is misdetected should not be seen as a bug, and unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't override it. `-pie` allows for some extra security protections that are fundamentally incompatible with `-no-pie`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have developed an app with a UI based on Qt/C++. Users expect to open it by double-click in a file explorer. That's no possible if the mime type is wrongly guessed.  Is that a reason for '-no-pie'? Or are there other work-arounds?

Comment: @Andreas did you find work around ? Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 I have the exact same problem...

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud I am experiencing the same with my Qt/C++ compiled on 17.04. any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

To solve it on Qt/C++ GUI Applications, add the following line on the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie
```